# Как получить куки с VPS?

Tags: python

У меня есть VPS и код:

```
cookies = {'R3ACTLB': '*тут куки*'}
request = requests.get(url, cookies=cookies, headers=headers)
```

Для запроса мне нужны куки, как я могу получить куки VPS?

Comment: Может в реализации класса request должен быть способ обратиться к полученным куки? Что-то вроде print(request["cookie"])

Comment: вам VPS устанавливает куки?